# Implementing copy constructor for polymorphic class

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Suppose I'm dealing with the following header file(for experimental purposes):

```
class Base{
protected: 
    Data& data1;
public:
    Base(Data& data1);
    virtual Base* clone() const =0;
    virtual ~Base();
    virtual void do() = 0;
};
class Derived: public Base{
private:
     const int data2;
public:
     Derived(int data2, Data& data1);
     virtual Derived* clone() const;
     ~Derived(); 
}
```

I tried to implement these classes which are fairly simple:

```
Base:

Base::Base(Data& data1): data1{data1} {}
virtual Base::~Base() = default;

Derived: 

Derived::Derived(int data2, Data& data1): Base(data1), data2{data2} {}
virtual Derived* Derived::clone() const {
    return new Derived(*this);
}
virtual void Derived::do() {
    return;
}
```

So far so good, but I'm having a couple of issues:

1. Say I wanted to implement a copy constructor and a copy assignment operator for this hierarchy,
   should I do it in both classes? If so, is this a good way to do it? :

```
Base: 

Base::Base(const Base& other): Base(other.data1) {}
Base& Base::operator=(const Base& rhs){
    if(this == &rhs)
        return *this;
    data1 = rhs.data1; // is this possible? since data1 is a reference (cannot be reassigned)
    return *this;
}
```

and which is a proper way to do so for derived?:

```
Derived:

Derived::Derived(const Derived& other): Base(other.data1), data2{other.data2} {}
OR
Derived::Derived(const Derived& other): Derived(other.data2, other.data2) {}

Derived& Derived::operator=(const Derived& rhs){
    if(this == &rhs)
        return *this;
    data1 = rhs.data1;
    data2 = rhs.data2; // data2 is a const variable so this is probably invalid too 
    return *this;
}
```

2. Once I implement a copy constructor for derived, I get an 'Endless loop' warning when returning from clone() method. Why is that?
3. Is there a proper way to implement rule of 3/ rule of 5 for classes of such hierarchy?

Thanks ahead.

Comment: I highly recommend changing your coding guidelines so that member variables have a different naming scheme than method parameters.

Comment: A reference member and `const` members of a class cannot be reassigned, so are generally only able to be initialised in a constructor initialiser list.   If a class has such members (or a base with such members) there may be a case for explicitly NOT having an assignment operator and/or not having a copy constructor.

Comment: @Peter I get why copy assignment is problematic, but why is it not okay to have a copy constructor? and why would that cause an infinite loop?

Comment: *but why is it not okay to have a copy constructor?* -- The question you should ask yourself is this -- does it make logical sense to have copies of `Base`?  There are some situations where it doesn't logically make sense to copy an object, for example the `istream` and `ostream`'s are not copyable.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie in this case it's not needed since there aren't any raw pointers involved. But generally, this is an abstract class that does have data members. If I did wanna copy one of its derived classes, I assume I would need a copy constructor for it as well, wouldn't I?

Comment: You didn't understand completely.  Even if the object didn't have raw pointers, does it make *logical* sense to make a copy of the `Base` object?  The reason why streams are not copyable is not because those classes have pointers in them -- the reason is that it doesn't make complete sense to have a copy of a stream.  What would it mean to have a copy of, say, a file object?  Two objects now point to the same file?  The file can be closed multiple times?  Etc.  That's the reason why streams are not copyable.  The same thing with your `Base` object.  Does it make sense to have copies of it?

Comment: "*Once I implement a copy constructor for derived, I get an 'Endless loop' warning when returning from clone() method*" - [can't reproduce](https://ideone.com/Wcnt0H)

Answer (score 1):

> Say I wanted to implement a copy constructor and a copy assignment operator for this hierarchy, should I do it in both classes? If so, is this a good way to do it?

Yes, you have to provide copy constructor/assignment.

Best way, when possible/correct, is to use default.

For assignment, your issue is unrelated to hierarchy, but related to member you use:

Reference cannot be rebound. const member cannot be changed.

So default assignment cannot be generated, mark them as deleted.

```
class Base
{
// ...
    Base(const Base&) = default;
    Base& operator=(const Base&) = delete;
};

class Derived
{
// ...
    Derived(const Derived&) = default;
    Derived& operator=(const Derived&) = delete;
};
```

> Once I implement a copy constructor for derived, I get an 'Endless loop' warning when returning from clone() method. Why is that?

[Cannot reproduce from comment](https://ideone.com/Wcnt0H)

> Is there a proper way to implement rule of 3/ rule of 5 for classes of such hierarchy?

Hierarchy is unrelated to rule of 5/3/0.

Just respect rule of 5/3/0 for each class.

Comment: apparently that endless loop thing is a Clion bug. Regardless of that, I thought I had my head wrapped around when to use copy & move constructors\ assignment operators, but apparently I don't. Could you please clarify? Does it make sense to have an abstract base class, which also has a virtual clone method to also have a copy/move constructor/ assignment operator in it? Or maybe does it even make sense to have these if there's no clone method? If so, what level of visibility is appropriate? private/ protected? )Assuming it does have dynamic data allocated) Thanks.